# Foxpro print SELECT result into screen directly instead of open query result window?

Tags: visual-foxpro

In Foxpro command windows, If I type "SELECT * FROM Orders o JOIN OrderDetail od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID", its will open a new window (with a grid) to display ressult, can I print the result direct into the back screen? (like LIST or BROWSE result)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Foxpro, a SELECT statement can be directed TO PRINTER or TO SCREEN

For example:

```
 SELECT * FROM Orders o JOIN OrderDetail od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID ;
    TO SCREEN
 --or
    TO PRINTER
```

You can also add PROMPT when sending to the printer to have the printer dialog window display to direct output to a specific printer.

```
TO PRINTER PROMPT
```

Also, you can direct the output to a temporary file or cursor. Then perform commands such as LIST

```
 SELECT * FROM Orders o JOIN OrderDetail od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID ;
  INTO CURSOR MyCursorname
 LIST
 --Or
 LIST TO SCREEN
 --Or
 LIST TO PRINTER
```